# Does npyscreen support clickable grid rows?

Tags: python, python-2.7, npyscreen

npyscreen lets you create a grid, and even set `select_whole_line=True` so that an entire line is selected when you move through the grid with your arrow keys. Is it possible to do something when the user picks a row in the grid and hits enter?

Comment: Seems like I may need to add an even handler for the enter key to my GridColTitles widget somehow. Seeing if I can figure it out...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I can add this to my form class' create method:

```
self.grid_widget.add_handlers({curses.ascii.NL: self.do_stuff})
```

And then this to the form class:

```
def do_stuff(self, input):
    self.MyText.value = self.grid_widget.selected_row()
    self.MyText.display()
```

Note that I tried using curses.KEY_ENTER instead of curses.ascii.NL, but that didn't seem to work for some reason.